Postman - GraphQL string query
I am trying to replace GraphQL query with string Environment Variable. Basically I want to know is it possible to put query from variable as content for query field? (example on pic.2).
I tried to put is inside { {{myVariable}} }, with brackets and without. Also trued to use GRAPHQL VARIABLE, still no luck.
Environment:

I tried to use it as variable, but no luck

